# Why do I get this error when trying to use mysqldump command?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to back up and roll back the back up on a database, and I'm trying to see what's wrong:

> 'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

The above is what I get in the file that is exported. And this is what I run:

```
$database = 'logindb';

$backup = $location.'/'.$database.'_backup_'.date('Y').'_'.date('m').'_'.date('d').'.sql';

exec("mysqldump --opt -h localhost -u root logindb > $backup 2>&1", $output);
print_r($output);
```

As `$location` being my backup folder. So why do I get that error ?

And as additional info, I'm testing on localhost with XAAMP, the Apache server is running and MySQL is running as wel.

Comment: Sounds like `mysqldump` can't be found: it is either not installed (I don't know if you can isntall it seperately or that this would be very strange for a stack), or maybe your user (apache?) doesn't have rights for it?

Comment: If you trying to do this on shared hosting `mysqldump` can also be disabled.

Comment: I'm testing on localhost first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `mysqldump` is not in httpd user path.

I asume you work in Linux (or UNIX).

To know witch directory contains `mysqldump` you can execute `whereis mysqldump`.

Then you have two options:

- Check for mysqldump directory is in PATH environment variable of httpd user (usualy `www-data` user for apache server). And include it in PATH is it not present.
- Also you can execute `mysqldump` with full path:

Like this:

```
exec("/path_to_mysql_bins/mysqldump ...
```

Comment: And how do I find that path ?

Comment: I had to add `c:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump ...` , in there I found the `mysqldump.exe` file. But what would it happen when I run this on shared server ? I won't need that path right ? And also how would I rollback the db ?

Comment: You can parametrize path as you parametrize database connection.

Comment: Well, I would, but as a shared hosting, I don't have access to the mysql server folders, only my root domain folder. So having a path on shared host it's out of question, but for localhost.

Comment: Perhaps in your hosting mysqldump is in PATH. Elsewhere, if you can run it means that is in an available path. Ask your administrator hosting.

Answer (score 1):

The error is not a mysqldump error, it's a Windows error that says that it does not understand what `mysqldump` relates to. To fix that you can either include the path to mysqldump executable to the [environment variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) or run the exec command with a full path to the mysqldump executable (which you can find within XAMPP mysql folder).